# How to send POST requests to a Spring Boot REST API using Postman form-data?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, postman

I'm trying a very simple Spring Boot + MySql app using STS: https://github.com/acenelio/person01

Posting a new Person using raw body works fine. However, when trying to post using form-data, I get either a 400 HttpMessageNotReadableException or 415 HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException error, depending on which Content-type I set on Headers.

I provided some Postman printscreens here: https://sites.google.com/site/stackoverflownelioalves/arqs

What am I missing? I'm kinda new on Postman and Spring Boot. Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@RequestBody` annotation:

```
@RequestMapping("/addInvestorProfile")
    public @ResponseBody Boolean addInvestorProfile(@RequestBody() InvestorProfile profile
, @RequestParam(value = "sessionId") String sessionId) 
  {
            .... your content
            return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which version of your spring boot. First of all, almost all `spring mvc` or `spring boot` controller method will accept all request content-type when you are not add `consumer` param to `@RequestMapping` annotation. So, maybe there is some wrong usage of postman.And I am work with spring boot & postman well.

try to compare postman behavior by copy request to `curl`

Usually post a request use `curl` looks like:
`curl -XPOST UrlOfYourSpringBootEndPoint -d'body of your post'`
more detail of curl [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).